# Changing axis of rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say I've got a massless rod, at the end of which, I've attached 2 identical balls. Now say I drop the rod, such that it collides with the ground and for some reason, the coefficient of restitution of both the balls in their collision with the ground is different. In this case, the linear velocity would be different, due to the different coefficient of restitution. So, in order to keep their angular velocity the same, which is a requirement for rigid body rotation, at the instant the balls rebound, **shouldn't the axis of rotation be changed too?**

Comment: Where was the axis of rotation initially?

Comment: It wasn't rotating initially, it was just falling

Comment: Then the axis of rotation should be changed from where to where?